# Pandas DataFrame styler - How to style pandas dataframe as excel table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

[image]

How to style the pandas dataframe as an excel table (alternate row colour)?

Sample style:

[image]

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
```

Comment: use `df.style.apply` some function returning an alternate array `['background-color: red', 'background-color: blue',....]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your final goal is to save `to_excel`, the only way to retain the styling after export is using the `apply`-based methods:

- [`df.style.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) / [`df.style.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html) are the styling counterparts to `df.apply` / `df.applymap` and work analogously
- [`df.style.apply_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply_index.html) / [`df.style.applymap_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap_index.html) are the index styling counterparts **(requires pandas 1.4.0+)**

For the given sample, use [`df.style.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) to style each column with alternating row colors and [`df.style.applymap_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap_index.html) to style all row/col indexes:

```
css_alt_rows = 'background-color: powderblue; color: black;'
css_indexes = 'background-color: steelblue; color: white;'

(df.style.apply(lambda col: np.where(col.index % 2, css_alt_rows, None)) # alternating rows
         .applymap_index(lambda _: css_indexes, axis=0) # row indexes (pandas 1.4.0+)
         .applymap_index(lambda _: css_indexes, axis=1) # col indexes (pandas 1.4.0+)
).to_excel('styled.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

[image]

---

If you only care about the appearance in Jupyter, another option is to set properties for targeted selectors using [`df.style.set_table_styles`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_table_styles.html) **(requires pandas 1.2.0+):**

```
# pandas 1.2.0+
df.style.set_table_styles([
    {'selector': 'tr:nth-child(even)', 'props': css_alt_rows},
    {'selector': 'th', 'props': css_indexes},
])
```